# EasyNetQ classic queue on RabbitMq 3.8

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

Since RabbitMq version 3.8.0 queues are create with **x-queue-type: classic** by default, this seems to be causing an error on EasyNetQ.

Running the following snippet will trigger an error

```
this.bus.Receive(queueName, onMessage);
```

Error

```
The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'TheQueue' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'classic' of type 'longstr'', classId=50, methodId=10
```

I did some tests and I know for a fact that the problem is the queue type, I would like to be able to connect EasyNetQ to this kind of queue but I couldn find any reference in the documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Where is the queue being declared originally? The problem is that your easynetq is attempting to redeclare a queue that already exists with different parameters. There is not enough information here to figure out where that is happening.

Comment: @theMayer brings up a good point. Was this queue declared prior to upgrading to 3.8? I'd like to be able to reproduce and fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. It is in fact a bug in RabbitMQ. I created an issue report [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-common/issues/341) if you would like to follow along. The fix will ship in version `3.8.2`.

Comment: Ouchhh! I got regression in upgrading 3.8.1,
the QA test cluster is running-fine because the queues was already created in 3.7.4 , upgraded without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in 3.8.0.
I verified in 3.8.23 - The issue is resolved.
I was following this tutorial.
https://medium.com/swlh/guide-to-nest-js-rabbitmq-microservices-e1e8655d2853
It does clearly mention to use 3.8.2. I still tired 3.8.0 and hit the issue.